# Mac OS X High Sierra Finder Drag and Drop animation previews slow

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, drag-and-drop, macos-highsierra

MacBook Pro 2012 (mid), High Sierra Version 10.14.6 (18G103)
I'm in middle of a big photo-review-sorting operation. +50.000 images that I need to sort.
In Finder I select 300 images, drag it over to another (empty) folder and this usually happens:

- (rainbow beach ball comes up),
- under the cursor the images line up,
- +30 seconds later, it lines up vertically,
- then it tries to show bigger previews vertically
- +20 seconds
- and hopefully if quicklookd or Finder does not freeze then I can see it's ready to drop.
  (I could copy and then move, but don't quite like it, also yesterday that process needed 3 hours for 10000 pictures?)

Is it possible to disable drag-drop animations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change what the OS wants to do graphically, but you could skip the entire thing by copy/move instead of drag & drop.

Select pictures to move as normal then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  as a regular copy, then
Select the destination and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd> 
This will move instead of copy - in effect it's cut/paste as opposed to copy/paste.

This also works as a move on different partitions, not only to the same partition.

Comment: D'oh - you already said you didn't like copy/move… I think you're stuggling with drive speed. I'm guessing you still have a spinny rust HD. That's going to be slow as heck on High Sierra, which expects to see an SSD,

Comment: Using SSDs. Thing is that copy/cut/paste, with 10000 images makes pboard process go crazy. As mentioned, it took 3 hours for that operation to make the system responsive again.

Comment: I presume, then that you're moving to another drive. How about… copy/move to a folder on the same drive, then drag the folder? It might still fill the queue irritatingly, but it might stop the graphic. APFS should be pretty quick for the first move. That's essentially what I do with my photos - though I'm generally dealing in hundreds not thousands at a time; all types, RAW, TIF, PSD & JPG.

Comment: Same hard drive. APFS-SSD